# Compare the same range on different worksheets

Tags: vba, compare, range

I have a workbook with multiple sheets (Sheet 1, 2...etc) and a "Master" Sheet. I need to select a range from columns A:C until it meets a row with the value (tva) (including those rows). I want to compare that range from Master to the other sheets, and highlight the differences.
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7emOe.png) For example Master sheet has in A3 value "m".

This is what I have so far. I'm pretty new at this so any advice is appreciated :)

```
Sub comp()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    rngCell = Columns("A:C").Resize(Columns("A:C").Find(What:="tva", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row)
    rngCell.Select
     For Each rngCell In ws.Range
             If Not rngCell = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column) Then
                rngCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
             End If
       
    Next ws

 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why C was highlighted, any reason?

Comment: Because when I compare Master Sheet to the others, master has value "m" on A3 and the other sheets have value "c" on A3  which I need to highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code, although it is did not cover other column, but small adjustment only need to check until column C (col 3):

```
Sub comp()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim valuerow As Long, irow As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    valuerow = Cells.Find(What:="tva", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For irow = 1 To valuerow
    
        If ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value <> Worksheets("Master").Cells(irow, 1).Value Then
            ws.Cells(irow, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    
        If ws.Cells(irow, 2).Value <> Worksheets("Master").Cells(irow, 2).Value Then
         ws.Cells(irow, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For the column B and C it is okay if I write "ws.Cells(irow, 3)"?

Comment: Yes, you can repeat the if function by change column value to 2,3 then will achieve the same outcome. Your assumption is correct, you can perform in worksheet to test the result. See my edited result and vote or accept if help :)